# Doesn't this theorem contradict itself?

Tags: real-analysis

Here's the theorem: if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x=\sup \{q\in\mathbb{Q}:q>0 \text{ and }q^2<2\}$, then $x\geq 1$ and $x^2=2$. The proof is stated here: [MIT Real Analysis](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-100a-real-analysis-fall-2020/resources/mit18_100af20_lec_full2/)

But doesn't the theorem contradict itself? We all know $\sqrt{2}$ is not a rational number. Then how can $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x^2=2$?

Comment: Yeah, that's the point.

Comment: Maxima need to be in the set. Suprema don't.

Comment: The theorem just shows that if such an $x$ did happen to be in $\mathbb Q,$ then it would have some property. However it makes no attempt to prove that such an $x$ is actually in $\mathbb Q.$ So there's no contradiction.

Comment: Theorem 40 in that reference doesn't state that $x\in\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: You linked to a 92 page document. I guess you cannot be specific about *where* in that 92 page document you find that proof?

Comment: page 11 for anyone interested

Comment: It contradicts that $\sup X\in \mathbb Q.$ There is an assumption here, and you reach a contradiction. The assumption is that $\sup X$ is a rational number.

Comment: "If Y then $\sqrt 2$ is rational" means $Y$ can't be true.

Comment: .Good Question and Expected Question in MSE,  Man MSE should build some community restrictions.

Comment: Is this theorem trying to show that $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't have the least upper bound property?

Comment: Very well then. It seems to be large, and it probably contains multitudes.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem 27 (stated in the question, on page 11 of the document) would probably be better labeled as a Lemma, as it does not have much stand-alone purpose. The main point is Theorem 28, from which we conclude that $\mathbb{Q}$ does not have the least upper bound property. Theorem 27 is used to break up the contradiction argument in the proof of Theorem 28.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks!